# hyper-v generic failure when trying to make new vmswitch

Tags: windows, docker, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I can't do anything with hyper-v manager. Everything that i try gives the generic failure.

This all started after the update of 14-01-2020.

I even tried removing the updates but that doesn't because i can't remove 1 out of the 3.

Next option is reinstall.

What i have tried so far:

```
dism /online /Disable-feature /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

```
Try to uninstall the network adapter from the device manager, and install it again.
```

```
Enable inbound firewall rule for "Windows Management Instrumentation (DCOM-in)"
```

```
netcfg -d
```

When i try to get my VMswitches:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-VMSwitch
Get-VMSwitch : Generic failure
```

When i try to make a new VMswitch:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> New-VMSwitch -SwitchName "NAT-Switch" -SwitchType Internal -Verbose

VERBOSE: New-VMSwitch will create a new virtual switch "NAT-Switch".
New-VMSwitch : Failed while creating virtual Ethernet switch.
An unexpected error occurred: Provider is not capable of the attempted operation (0x80041024).
Failed while creating virtual Ethernet switch.
The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service encountered an unexpected error: Provider is not capable of the
attempted operation (0x80041024).
At line:1 char:1
+ New-VMSwitch -SwitchName "NAT-Switch" -SwitchType Internal -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-VMSwitch], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVMSwitch
```

My docker can't run as well:

```
[01:59:13.556][PowerShell        ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Create True -VhdPathOverride C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data\DockerDesktop.vhdx -VhdSize 68719476736 -SwitchSubnetAddress 10.0.75.0 -SwitchSubnetMaskSize 28 -PreferredIPAddress  -CPUs 2 -Memory 2048 -IsoFile C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\docker-desktop.iso -Verbose True -ErrorAction Stop
[01:59:13.607][HyperV            ][Info   ] Creating Switch: DockerNAT...
[01:59:13.654][HyperV            ][Error  ] Unable to create: System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Generic failure 
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Docker.Core.PowerShell.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<InvokeAsync>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.PowerShell.<InvokeAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.PowerShell.<RunAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Even though all these errors are generated. I can't seem to find a single one of them in the Windows Event Viewer.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same issue (almost exactly 1 year later!). Thanks

Comment: @adam197 Yes I reinstalled windows. But I think the link in the First answer could also help! I already reinstalled before that comment came so never could test it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Updating to Windows 10 1909 using the [update assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3159635/windows-10-update-assistant) solved the issue for me.